# Throw Simple Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I'm looking to learn how to throw a super simple exception in java. I have the following:

```
public Percolation(int N) // create N-by-N grid, with all sites blocked
{
    if(N < 1)
        throw new Exception("N must be greater than zero.");

    grid = new boolean[N * N + 2];
    dimension = N;
    grid[0] = true;
    grid[N+1] = true;       
    unionStruct = new QuickFindUF(N+2);
}
```

It's not compiling, but that's the type of thing I'm looking to do. What's the proper syntax to do this?

Comment: When writing a question like this, you should state what the error you receive is.

Comment: Read the JSL, really. Every single book or document that introduces exceptions in Java mentions that your functions have to declare those *checked* exceptions that you are going to throw. Read the documentation available on *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions. Also, get into the habit of telling people what error you are getting. Telling people "it's not compiling" without telling them what error the compiler tells you, that's just offensive. People don't read minds nor are they capable of looking at your monitor telepathically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're throwing a checked exception without declaring the exception you're throwing.  In your case you should probably be throwing an exception derived from RuntimeException instead, and these are not checked (meaning you don't have to declare them).  So the two ways to fix this are

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("N must be greater than zero."); // unchecked
```

or

```
public Percolation(int N) throws Exception
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare that the constructor throws an Exception

```
public Percolation(int N) throws Exception {} //create N-by-N grid, with all sites blocked
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are not specifying that an exception is being thrown. Tell us what error you recieve.

In the meantime, try this:

```
    public Percolation(int N) throws Exception
{
    if(N < 1)
        throw new Exception("N must be greater than zero.");
    ...
```

There are two types of exceptions in Java:

1. Compiler enforced exceptions ("checked exceptions").
2. Runtime exceptions ("unchecked exceptions").

Either throw an unchecked exception, or specify that your exception is thrown, as I've done in the code above.

In this case, the unchecked exception you are looking for would be `IllegalArgumentException`.